# Extract data from ListView

Tags: android, listview

I populated my ListView with data from my database table.

How can I get data from selected item?

This is how I populate ListView:

```
    SimpleCursorAdapter SimpleCursorAdapter;
ListView listCategories = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.categoryList);
categoryRepo categoryRepo = new categoryRepo(this);
TextView textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

private void displayCategories()
{
    Cursor cursor = categoryRepo.getCategories();

    if (cursor == null)
    {
        textview.setText("Error");
        return;
    }
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0)
    {
        textview.setText("No categories.");
        return;
    }

    String[] from = new String[] {category.KEY_CATEGORY_NAME};
    int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

    SimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursor,from,to,0);
    listCategories.setAdapter(SimpleCursorAdapter);

}
```

I know that I can do this by using listCategories.setOnItemClickListener , but I do not know how. Thank you for help.

I want to get CATEGORY_NAME value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listCategories.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         Cursor cursor = (Cursor) SimpleCursorAdapter.getItem(position);
    }
});
```

[How to get string from selected item of SimpleCursorAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376860/how-to-get-string-from-selected-item-of-simplecursoradapter)

Comment: Ok, but how can I get this data in string?
Never mind, I figured it out. Thank you! It works better than I expected.
(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(category.KEY_ID)))

Comment: It works good, but can I ask you to explain me what do mean parameters in OnItemClick method?, I mean arg0, arg1 and arg3??

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
listCategories.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                String selectedValue = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(category.KEY_CATEGORY_NAME));
                // do what ever you want here
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I got this error : java.lang.ClassCastException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: Edited, have a look